# Maven release plugin - how to set svn:ignores

Tags: svn, maven-2, hudson, release, svnignore

I have a maven project which generates files which are ignored in Eclipse by the global setting (Team -> Ignored Resources) and therefore are not going into svn.

If I want to release the project on our build server with hudson it fails as it says that the local copy has local changes (the generated files). How to I tell maven there to ignore them ?

Where do I have to configure what ?

Answer (score 2):

Tell SVN to ignore them. Some info [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm) and [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)